# Designing Eddy Current Sensor?

Tags: current, sensor, coil, current-sensing, current-sensor

I am looking to build a eddy current sensor, I am having difficulty finding information on how I should be designing the sensor to fit my needs. There's a few studies and articles I've found that provide some details as to how the circuit is designed, it does seem relatively simple. Though I am trying to keep costs low using a rather simple circuit. The article is a bit old but it seems this would be the basis for the sensor:

[image: eddy current sensor circuit]

Image is from Figure 8 at:
https://www.fierceelectronics.com/components/designing-and-building-eddy-current-position-sensor

Sorry for the quality but the article is from the 90s and I haven't been able to find a similar design from a newer article. From what I understand this outputs a signal that can then be read by a cheap micro controller that can then calculate and adjust the output through any processing that might need to happen.

There are some things I don't really understand about the circuit. I guess it would need to be customized depending on the type of material being detected. Comparing stainless steel and aluminum for example would need different specs. As well as the coil itself that is used for sensing, I can't really find any information on what would need to be done with the coil, what kind of spacing and size. I'd need a flat coil which apparently can be done using a PCB with the coil printed onto the PCB. Though I don't know what line thickness, spacing, or the size of the coil should for my needs. I just vaguely know that the larger the coil the less precise it ends up being. I do need it to be fairly precise so I don't know what size is good or even how the quality of the PCB might impact the sensor.

I'd also need some sort of temperature compensation. The eddy current will give a different reading depending on the ambient temperature, in my case the ambient temperature might be between 20-75 Celsius. The surface that the sensor would be used on can also go up to 120 Celsius. I'm not sure if that would impact the sensor though, or if it is only the ambient/sensor temperature.

Comment: What is the volume of target? Is it some sheet like 100x100mm or some small part like 3mm screw? I am asking because it tells you how big the coil has to be to avoid target volume dependecies.

Comment: Mark, you don't say much about the situation. But as [this article](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/10/8/7874) makes clear, often details about what you are doing matter as to how you design and follow through with your measurement system. Perhaps you should write more.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický It would be a for a sheet, I guess more specifically it would be for the bed of a 3d printer. So usually it is an aluminum plate with some sort of surface on top which could just be painters tape or a magnet with a steel spring plate that would sit on top of the magnet and is usually rather thin.